# Embed image in an email Office 2003 with VSTO

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, ms-office

How could embed an image in an email with VSTO for Office 2003, C # and VS2005 (not as attachment but as part of the mail)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this

```
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=278600
```